# A Puzzle With the Difficulty Level of Dessert

Tags: wordplay, cipher, steganography

I have built an encoded message here. Read and ponder. In this particular case I have encoded the name of an American known all over. My method is simple. Don't be fooled. Although this is a short one, message lengths can be extended arbitrarily.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The title means

> "easy as pie".

We can

> count the digits of pi, then take the first letter of each word -- for instance, the first word is BUILT, since it's the **3**rd word. The second is AN, since it's **1** word after built. Then count **4** to get to READ...
>
>
>  Doing this gives the name BARACK OBAMA.

Comment: Congratulations. Less time than it took for me to type it in!